Random effects lavaan
I am running a sem() model and I am trying to include a random effects.
Dataframe:
test <- data.frame(Person = c("a", "a","a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
                 TrialVariable = c(1, 5, 3, 2, 7,2, 1,1,1),
                 Trait1 = (c(2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3)),
                 Trait2 = (c(12,12,12,10,10,10,8,8,8)),
                 Trait3 = (c(2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3)),
                 Trait4 = (c(17,17,17,12,12,12,8,8,8)))

Sem model specification
model <- '

# regressions
TrialVariable ~ Trait4
Latent1 ~ TrialVariable

# latent construct
Latent1 =~ Trait1 + Trait2 + Trait3
'

I am in essence trying to run this model in a way so that the regression "TrialVariable ~ Trait4" has random intercept and slope grouped by "Person". In lmer this might look something like this:
regression1 <- lmer(TrialVariable ~ Trait4 +
            (1 |Person), data = test)

In lavaan I have tried to group by "Person"
mod.est <- sem(
  model = model,
  data = test,
  group = "Person",
  estimator = "ULS"
)

but this outputs the error "Error: lavaan->lav_data_full():
some variables have no variance in group 1 : Trait1 Trait2 Trait3 Trait4".
I have not been able to find a solution to this.

All your trait variables are Level-2 variables, so they don't vary within person.
In an actual MLSEM, you would only include these in the Level-2 model syntax: https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/multilevel.html  But lavaan only estimates random intercepts.  The PLmixed package might be an option: https://njrockwood.com/plmixed

After trying this solution, it seems the 2-level approach doesn't quite solve the problem because when the "Latent1" construct is put in level 1 we get the no-variance problem, but if the Latent1 construct is put in level 2 the level 1 regression "Latent1 ~ TrialVariable" can't find the Latent1 construct and still don't run.


I am in essence trying to run this model in a way so that the regression "TrialVariable ~ Trait4" has random intercept and slope

For that to work, Trait4 would have to be a Level-1 variable.  In your reprex data, it varies only between (not within) Person, so it can only have a (Level-2) fixed effect.
This is what Preacher et al. (2010, Table 1) referred to as a 2-1-2 design, where only the mediator (TrialVariable) is measured at Level 1.  This means that the (in)direct effects of Trait4 on Latent1 only occur at Level 2 (i.e., the only relevant variance in TrialVariable is in its Person means).
You could fit the model to your Level-2 data. This involves calculating the Level-2 component of TrialVariable (i.e., Person means). You can use aggregate() to save those with nonredundant rows of the other Level-2 variables:
testL2 <- aggregate(cbind(TrialVariable, Trait1, Trait2, Trait3, Trait4) ~ Person,
                    data = test, FUN = mean)
mod.est <- sem(
  model = model,
  data = testL2,
  #group = "Person",
  estimator = "ULS"
)

Note that this example fails with your reprex because some of your variables are perfectly correlated (hard to avoid with only 3 Level-2 observations). You can edit your test data to try it with different values, and maybe 5 observations to avoid the sample covariance matrix being non-positive definite.  And make Trait4 a Level-1 variable, if that is what you intended (to have a random slope).

Thank you for this response, but if I understand your post correctly this should run if I do a 2-level model (as suggested above) with the "TrialVariable ~ Trait4" regression at level 2 and the "Latent1 ~ TrialVariable" at level 1 (since TrialVariable does vary within-person). However, when I try this, the model cannot 'find' Latent1 - I suspect because the latent variable is defined at level 2 (by loading factors with no within-person variance).
Is it possible in Lavaan to run the "Latent1 ~ TrialVariable" regression with mixed effects?

I was using the same model object in your reprex, so it is a single-level model (including the measurement model for Latent1), but fitted to person-level data.  TrialVariable varies within person, but only variances between person-means can explain the between-person differences in Latent1.  That is why my syntax creates the Level-2 data set (testL2) and applies your model to it.
